# How to use SQL Server Views with EF Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I've reverse engineered a small database that contains a number of tables and views into EF 5 code first.

When I do this, I get a set of models and mapping classes for each of my tables and these work well when I try to query the database using the generated `DbContext`.

It also generates POCO classes for each of my views, but when I run `Enable-Migrations` and `Add-Migration` using the Package Manager Console, the migration does not re-create the SQL Server views.

I have tried updating the migration manually to create the views using custom SQL like so:

```
Sql("CREATE VIEW [dbo].[viewUsersDeactivated] "
          + "AS "
          + "SELECT ... ");
```

This works fine when I run `Update-Database`, but the SQL script that is output from the `Update-Database -Script` command does not seem to be valid, resulting in the following error:

> 'CREATE VIEW' must be the only statement in the batch.

Inserting `Sql("GO");` between each of the custom SQL statements works for the script generation, but then I can no longer update using `Update-Database`, and I can't find a way that works for both.

So my question boils down to: **How can I include SQL Server views in a code first migration script such that I can create a database both using `Update-Database` and via production scripts generated using `Update-Database -Script`?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not entirely sure this is best practice, and someone else might have a better solution, but I got around this by wrapping the entire view creation script in an Execute, thus:

```
var sql = "CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TheViewName] AS ......."
sql = sql.Replace("'", "''"); // sanitize the sql string
sql = string.Format("EXECUTE sp_executesql N'{0}'", sql);
Sql(sql);
```

Comment: Thanks @greg, this looks really promising!

Comment: It would be good if there was a way for SQL statements to be checked before execution... My lecturer tells me to only use them in exceptional circumstances. Am currently scouring Google looking for different ways to create views (without manual queries), but might have to go the manual route if time runs out.