# LinqToEntities row and related entity count

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm struggling to find suitable syntax to replicate the following SQL in Linq-to-Entities:

```sql
SELECT 
    company.*, count(people.companyid) as cnt  
FROM company 
INNER JOIN people on company.id = people.companyid
GROUP BY company.id
```

I have a foreign key relationship defined in the database and subsequently in the Entity Framework model (`.edmx`)

I've disabled lazy loading so I think I would need to include the related table (people) however it seems inefficient in my resulting razor view (for the list of companies) to do a count foreach row. i.e. it will be populating a collection of people for each company.

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
//..... 
     <label>Company Members:</label>
     <div>@item.people.count</div>
    }
```

An example shows how to do this for a single entity but I need this count for each of my companies

```
<!-- language: lang-c#-->
    using (var context = new UnicornsContext())
    {
        var princess = context.Princesses.Find(1);

        // Count how many unicorns the princess owns 
        var unicornHaul = context.Entry(princess)
                              .Collection(p => p.Unicorns)
                              .Query()
                              .Count();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be equivalent to your query

```
from c in context.Companies
group c by c.Id into g
select new {Company = g.First(), CNT = g.First().People().Count}
```

Although for what you need, you don't need to do `groupby` at all

```
from c in context.Companies
//group c by c.Id into g
select new {Company = c, CNT = c.People().Count}
```

Comment: thanks that works however now i need to change my razor view from model IEnumerable<companies> to model List<KeyValuePair<companies,Int32>>  i think as the model is different ?

Comment: This will return you list of anonymous objects where each object has Company (company type) and Count (int), you can decide how you want to send it back since you can't really return anonymous from database. You can return a KeyValuePair<Company, int> for example.

Comment: yes i decided to use a viewmodel with a company property and a int32 property in the linqtoentities select rather than the anonymous type cheers

Answer (score 0):

Returning an anonymous type to your View can get tricky, as you noted. Instead of a View Model (and all that overhead and maintenance), you can add a property to your model but flag it `[NotMapped]` from the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace. That gives you a place within the object itself (as opposed to a 'sidecar') without affecting your database in any way.

See [How To Count Associated Entities Without Fetching Them In Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010897/how-to-count-associated-entities-without-fetching-them-in-entity-framework/30241584#30241584)